# Why do we not get a performance improvement with PSeq?

Tags: parallel-processing, f#, seq, plinq

## Question

We figured that processing each "tail permutation" in parallel would decrease the real running time of this algorithm. Why does it not? How if at all can we configure PSeq to improve the running time?

```
let rec permute (xs:'t list) = 
    if xs.Length = 1 then [xs]
    else ([], permute xs.Tail)
        // Why do we not get a performance 
        // improvement when we use PSeq here
        // relative to using Seq?
        ||> PSeq.fold (fun acc ps -> 
            (insertAtEach xs.Head ps)@acc)

permute ["A";"B";"C"] |> ignore
```

We figured that the permutations work would be split as follows, and that the `insertAtEach` phase of the algorithm would work in parallel.

```
                        [C]

             [BC]                [CB]

[ABC] [BCA] [BCA]                [ACB] [CAB] [CBA]

            CPU01                CPU02
```

It is actually slower in parallel even when we use a large initial list such as `permute [0..9]`. We have not not figured out whether `withDegreeOfParallelism` and related PSeq options will help.

## Aside

Here is the rest of the code listing:

```
let put a q xs =
    ([], xs)
        ||> Seq.fold (fun acc x ->
            if x = q then a::x::acc
            else x::acc)
        |> List.rev

// Insert x at each possible location in xs
let insertAtEach a xs =
    ([a::xs], xs)
        ||> Seq.fold (fun acc x ->
            (put a x xs)::acc)
```

Comment: The F# parallelism code has a relative high fixed cost, as I understand it, and even doing `permute [0..9]` might not be enough to overcome the fixed cost. I'd suggest first doing multiple measurements: compare serial vs. parallel running time for permutations of 8 elements, then 9, then 10, then 11, then 12... and graph the times. Does it look like the parallel version is going to stay ahead of the serial version all the time? Then there might be some reason why the parallel version is inefficient. But if it looks like the parallel version will eventually catch up, then it's just fixed cost.

Comment: @rmunn I'll need to try that with a different approach, because in the existing implementation, `permute [0..10]` takes far too long (more than 15-minutes) with either the Seq or the PSeq approach even though `permute [0..9]` only takes 15 seconds or so.

Comment: @rmunn while what you said is generally correct, in this particular case the issue is that fold is not parallelizable in principle. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PSeq.fold` doesn't do what you think it does. `PSeq.fold` is actually not parallel at all. It's sequential.

---

You can't just throw the word "parallel" somewhere in the middle of your algorithm and hope for the best. That's not how parallelization works. You have to actually understand what's going on, what happens in parallel, what is sequential, what can be parallelized in principle, and what cannot.

Take the `fold` for example: it applies the provided folding function to every element of the sequence *and* the result of the previous call. Since every next call must have the result of the previous call before it can execute, it's pretty obvious that `fold` cannot be carried out in parallel at all. Has to be sequential. And in fact, that's what `PSeq.fold` actually does if you look at its [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a38c5000be0d4b98445ef43d642614d0e8d8f82d/src/System.Linq.Parallel/src/System/Linq/ParallelEnumerable.cs#L1686). So you get some overhead for converting to a `ParallelSequence` every time, but no gain.

Now, if you look at your algorithm carefully, you can tease out the parallelizable part. What your algorithm does:

1. Recursively compute permutations of the tail.
2. For every one of those permutations, explode it by inserting the head at every index.
3. Concatenate all results of step 2.

When you put it like this, it's easy to see that step 2 doesn't really depend on anything but itself. Every tail permutation is processed completely separately from all others.

Of course, this isn't evident just from looking at your source code, because you've combined steps 2 and 3 in one expression `(insertAtEach xs.Head ps)@acc`, but it's easy to tease apart using the following general identity:

```
xs |> fold (fun a x -> g a (f x))
    ===
xs |> map f |> fold (fun a x -> g a x)
```

That is, instead of applying function `f` to every element `x` during the `fold`, you can apply it to every element "in advance" using `map`.

Applying this idea to your algorithm, you get:

```
let rec permute (xs:'t list) = 
    if xs.Length = 1 then [xs]
    else permute xs.Tail 
         |> Seq.map (insertAtEach xs.Head)
         |> Seq.fold (fun acc ps -> ps@acc) []
```

Now it's easy to see that the `Seq.map` step is the parallelizable one: `map` applies the function to each element independently of other elements, so it *can* in principle work in parallel. Just replace `Seq` with `PSeq` and you got yourself the parallel version:

```
let rec permute (xs:'t list) = 
    if xs.Length = 1 then [xs]
    else permute xs.Tail 
         |> PSeq.map (insertAtEach xs.Head)
         |> PSeq.fold (fun acc ps -> ps@acc) []
```

Whether or not `PSeq` actually does perform `map` in parallel is another matter, but that should be easily verifiable empirically.

And indeed, on my machine, the parallel version consistently outperforms the sequential version for lists of 7 to 10 elements (11-element list caused an OOM).

---

P.S. keep in mind that, when measuring time, you need to force the resulting sequence first (e.g. by converting it to a list or taking `Seq.last`). Otherwise all you're measuring is just the parallelization overhead cost.

P.P.S. [here's a gist with my benchmark code](https://gist.github.com/fsoikin/806dba27972d7de183ac6cdb17ae5cfc).

Comment: You mentioned that "PSeq.fold is actually not parallel at all. It's sequential." Based on the source code, you're right. Oddly, its [documentation](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq/reference/fsharp-collections-parallelseq-pseqmodule.html) says otherwise: "Operates in parallel, using System.Linq.Parallel." Even the [corefx documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a38c5000be0d4b98445ef43d642614d0e8d8f82d/src/System.Linq.Parallel/src/System/Linq/ParallelEnumerable.cs#L1655) says it opperates in parallel. Do you know what the documentation means by that?

Comment: That's probably because documentation is generated by some sort of template, and nobody had the sense to refine it. Documentation is not a replacement for your own thought. You have to always think about what you're doing. That's why software engineers are so highly paid.

Comment: In theory you could parallelize a fold operation if you know that the operation is associative. E.g., if you were doing `Array.fold (+)` (let's pretend for a moment that `Array.sum` doesn't exist), then because the equation (a + b) + c = a + (b + c) will ALWAYS hold for all values of a, b and c, you could safely have the first two elements of the array added on CPU 1, the third and fourth elements added on CPU 2, and so on. But since you won't always be folding over an associative operation, PSeq.fold can't assume anything, so it has to do each step serially.

Comment: Re: the misleading documentation, I opened [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28655) in the corefx repo.

Comment: @rmunn That makes sense to me and reminds me that we can implement most (if not all) LINQ operations in terms of the Aggregate operation.

Answer (score 3):

### Part I.: " *Why* does it not? "

Because each conversion ( transformation ) from a **`SEQ -- -- --`** process-execution scheduling into **`PAR -- || ||`** requires some efforts to be done, which demonstrate themselves as indeed visibly materialised `[TIME]`-domain and `[SPACE]`-domain **setup + termination overhead costs**.

For more details review the [**re-formulated** Amdahl's Law, particularly the naive-form **Fig.1**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) versus the **Section: Criticism** and there later derived **overhead-strict re-formulation of the Law.**

There is no way to avoid taxes and overhead-costs from ever being paid...

In parallel-computing and a bit less intensively in the just-concurrent computing environments, it is indeed **very easy to pay way more than receive** in exchange.

Plus, one may find indeed numerous examples and surprises posted here, on Stack Overflow, using a search tag [parallelism-amdahl](/questions/tagged/parallelism-amdahl), you can see many examples with benchmarked overhead-costs ( if users remained open-minded and were systematic enough to run them and to record and post the realistic `[TIME]`-domain costs ).

---

### Part II.: " *How* if at all can we ... improve the running time? "

No one can escape from overhead-strict, atomic-processing aware re-formulated Amdahl's Law.

No one can.

Yet, this tool gives also a design-side advantage, if used during initial product planning.

Net resulting processing overheads are influenced by resources pool sizes, by mandatory data-transfers, by (un-)avoided sharing and/or other forms of mutual-dependencies, by results' sizes being returned back upon `{` concurrent `|` parallel `}`-processing termination -- **all these add-on costs can be systematically benchmarked**, so as to well understand the costs of doing so, down to the memory allocation costs, garbage collections or similar realistic modus operandi deallocation overheads.

Given a known deployment ecosystem, no one is forbidden from using the benchmarked data for the systematic costs-benefits evaluation among going into pure-serial / distributed / parallel process execution there.

Given this fine-grained knowledge was benchmarked, it can serve as **a fair metric to solve The Dilemma**: i.e. --  What is the minimum size of the **`PAR -- ||||`** section, so that it at least pays for its own un-avoidable `{ setup + termination }`-overhead-add-on-costs?

Not having done either of these, one will just get surprised, how expensive was the process of re-factoring, contrasted with a **straight "negative"** or a way worse-than-expected processing performance improvement.

**Always**: Benchmark, benchmark, benchmark.

**Next**: Simply never choose the more expensive way.

Comment: Um... what? There's some useful information here, but your writing style makes it extremely hard to decipher what you're saying. Could you try to explain this in simpler language? Or at least explain what you mean by shorthand like `SEQ -- -- --` vs `PAR -- || ||`? A simplified explanation without so much opaque shorthand would go a long way towards making this answer comprehensible.